# Following code is failing to find intersection of two lists

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I am doing [LC:60](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/description/) which is about finding intersection of two linked lists. I wrote following code based on this logic

- find length of both lists.
- advance 1 pointer of long list to the difference of the length
- compare both lists from this point onwards.

This is working for all test-cases except for test case where two lists have same input i.e., `[2, 2, 4, 5, 4]` but the intersection node is node `4`.

Here is the code

```java
public class Solution {
    public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {
        int aN = 0;
        ListNode a = headA;
        while (a != null) {
            aN++;
            a = a.next;
        }    

        int bN = 0;
        ListNode b = headB;
        while (b != null) {
            bN++;
            b = b.next;
        }

        ListNode longList = (aN > bN) ? headA : headB;
        ListNode shortList = (aN < bN) ? headA : headB;

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(aN - bN); i++) {
            longList = longList.next;
        }

        while (longList != null && shortList != null) {
            if (longList == shortList) { return longList; }
            longList = longList.next;
            shortList = shortList.next;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The way question is phrased, I want to check if a node is same (common) in two lists "regardless" of its value.

Comment: `ListNode shortList = (aN <= bN) ? headA : headB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these statements:

```
    ListNode longList = (aN > bN) ? headA : headB;
    ListNode shortList = (aN < bN) ? headA : headB;
```

If both lists have the same size, then both `longList` and `shortList` will be set to `headB`. You should have a ternary condition that is the exact opposite (`<=` for the second one), or maybe more intuitive, use the same condition but swap the operands in the second assignment:

```
    ListNode longList = (aN > bN) ? headA : headB;
    ListNode shortList = (aN > bN) ? headB : headA;
```

Comment: I'm not convinced whether it would be more readable or intuitive, but you could also write `ListNode shortList = (longList == headA) ? headB : headA;`, that is, make `shortList` the reference that `longList` is not.